# Pulling in most recent feed on instagram without using hashtag

Tags: javascript, instagram

I'm currently using some javascript that pulls in the 6 most recent images from the hashtag that I search for. I want to pull in the 6 most recent images overall without using a hashtag to search for specific images.

What do I need to add into this code to pull the 6 most recent images from a user and not a hashtag

```
  $(function() {
var cmdURL, embedImage, onPhotoLoaded, param, tag_name, userid,
param = {
access_token: 'xxxxxx', // feel free to change it with your own access token
count: 6 // the total number of images
},
```

userId = '11941870',
    tag = '',  //your user id. you can find this one out by looking into one of your pictures uri
    tag_name = '#photowall',
    cmdURL = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tag + '/media/recent?callback=?';

```
 embedImage = function(photo) {
var a, img;
img = $('<img/>').attr({
  //'src': photo.images.thumbnail.url,
  //'width': photo.images.thumbnail.width,
  //'height': photo.images.thumbnail.height
  'src': photo.images.standard_resolution.url,
  'width': photo.images.standard_resolution.width,
  'height': photo.images.standard_resolution.height
});
a = $('<a />').attr({
  'href': photo.images.standard_resolution.url,
  'target': '_blank',
  'class': 'pull-left'
}).append(img).appendTo(tag_name);
    };

onPhotoLoaded = function(data) {
var photo, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
if (data.meta.code === 200 && data.data) {
  _ref = data.data;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    photo = _ref[_i];
    _results.push(embedImage(photo));
  }
  return _results;
}
};
return $.getJSON(cmdURL, param, onPhotoLoaded);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Instagram Api there is this call

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<user_id>/media/recent
```

that will return the most recent pics of the user.

I think you can check how it works here https://instagram.com/developer/api-console/

Comment: I've updated the code above to show that i've added in the code for UserId, but nothing seems to want to pull through at all now. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Your code is still using tag api url. It should be cmdURL = 'ht tps://api. instagram.com/v1/users/'+userId+'/media/recent?callback=?';